# Implementing most recent post in my index.html.erb Rails template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've been putting the finishing touches on my app all day with the help of some useful answers here and would like to know how this feature can be executed. I have an idea set up in my `post_controller` file where I want to show the top 10 most recent posts created based on the date that they were created. I also plan on doing this for my comments as well laster on. I am showing all users post in the `views/post/index.html.erb` file. I wrote this line of code in the `posts_controller: posts = Post.order('created_at DESC').limit(10)`. I've searched here thoroughly but don't understand how some other users got this to work, any insight? Thanks in advance.

posts_controller

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :vote]
  before_action :require_user, only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update, :vote]
  before_action :require_creator, only:[:edit, :update]

  def index
    posts = Post.order('created_at DESC').limit(10)
    @posts = Post.all.page(params[:page]).per_page(10)
  end

  def show
    @comment = Comment.new
  end

  def new
    @post = Post.new
  end

  def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)
    @post.creator = current_user

    if @post.save
      flash[:notice] = "You created a post!"
      redirect_to posts_path
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    if @post.update(post_params)
      flash[:notice] = "You updated the post!"
      redirect_to post_path(@post)
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

  def vote
    Vote.create(voteable: @post, creator: current_user, vote: params[:vote])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js { render :vote } # Renders views/posts/vote.js.erb
    end
  end

  private
  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:url, :title, :description)
  end

  def set_post
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  def require_creator
    access_denied if @post.creator != current_user
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `posts` variable you've declared in your `index` action will not be available in your view.  What you need to do is update the line where you're retrieving the posts using instance variable as follows:

```
def index
    @posts = Post.page(params[:page]).order('created_at DESC').per_page(10)
end
```

Comment: vinodadhikary - Shouldn't this line of code work in my `post_controller.rb` file. I added this in the `def show action`...`@comment_date_order = Comment.find(params[:id]).order('created_at DESC')`

Comment: @user2045764, I would suggest asking a new question for this as this is different from this question.  For your question in comment, I think you need to do `Post.find(params[:id]).comments`.  Please give that a try.

Comment: No luck, but i'll ask again I too tried that `.comments`. Thanks for all your help.